# Pyspark/Python Method

Tags: python, apache-spark, oop, pyspark

I am trying to extend the Optimus use case for my Pyspark transformation.

However I stumbled on the below `.add_columns()` method doesn't carry forward my Pyspark dataframe method and the `.add_columns_2()` method carries forward the methods at IDE level.

Why I couldn't list the methods related to the Pyspark dataframe post the assignment ?

```py
class OptExtender:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self._df = df

    def add_columns(self, column):
        self._df ## ==> This shows the methods related to pyspark dataframe methods 
        self._df = self._df.withColumn(column, lit('Hello'))
        self._df ## ==> This doesn't list the Pyspark dataframe methods 
        return self

    def add_columns_2(self, column):
        self._df ## ==> This shows the methods related to pyspark dataframe methods 
        def add_columns(column):
             self._df = self._df.withColumn(column, lit('Hello'))
        self._df ## ==> This shows the Pyspark dataframe methods 
        return self
```

Comment: Did you tried to do this just extending the class? `class OptExtender(DataFrame)` ???

Comment: I don't wanna be rude and I don't know the context of this. But why `withColumn` is not enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange that it doesn't work, because the `.withColumn()` returns a Dataframe object, take a look in source [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py).

You can try the following, explicitly declare the type of the `_df` attribute :

```
from pyspark.sql import Dataframe

class OptExtender:
    def __init__(self, df):
       self._df: Dataframe  = df    

def add_columns(self, column):
    self._df = self._df.withColumn(column, lit('Hello'))
    self._df ## ==> Now it should work
    return self._df
```